# The 'npx create-react-app' is not working (missing dependency)

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

I don't know how to solve this dependency issue. Some months ago I did use the create-react-app without any problems.

```
Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts...
PS C:\Users\me\Desktop\React> npx create-react-app my-app

Creating a new React app in C:\Users\me\Desktop\React\my-app.

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts...

npm ERR! code ETARGET
npm ERR! notarget No matching version found for confusing-browser-globals@^1.0.9
npm ERR! notarget In most cases you or one of your dependencies are requesting
npm ERR! notarget a package version that doesn't exist.
npm ERR! notarget
npm ERR! notarget It was specified as a dependency of 'eslint-config-react-app'
npm ERR! notarget

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-09-24T11_36_58_826Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Is this the output of `npm start` or `npm install`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
npm install

npm start
```